# How can I change the size of 'QMessageBox' in my PyQt6 application?

Tags: pyqt6

How to set the size of 'QMessageBox'?

```
info = QMessageBox(self)
info.setWindowTitle("Information")
info.setText("Password is not correct")
info.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Warning)
info.exec()
```

I have write the above code, but i don't know how to set the size of 'QMessageBox'.

How to set the size of 'QMessageBox'?